# Determine if all items in ICollection<T> are not contained in List<T> using Linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

so this is the setup:

**Rule Model**

```
public class Rule
{
    public int RuleId { get; set; }
    public BillOfMaterial BillOfMaterial { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Option> MustNotContainAllOptions { get; set; }
}
```

**Option Model**

```
public class Option
{
    public int OptionId { get; set; }
    public string OptionCode { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Rule> MustNotContainAllRules { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to query a rule for its bill of materials from a given base and list of options. The only condition at this point is that the rule can't contain any of a given list of options.

**Example Input**

Input Options: PA,PB

**Example Rule**

Rule: MustNotContainOptions = PA, Bill Of Material = BOM1

In this case the query should return nothing since the input has option PA

**What I have tried**

OptionList = The input list of options

```
   var MustNotContainAnyQuery = (from rule in db.Rules
                                 where rule.MustNotContainAllOptions.Any(option => !OptionList.Contains(option.OptionCode))
                                 select rule.BillOfMaterial.BomNumber);
```

and

```
var MustNotContainAnyQuery = (from rule in db.Rules
                              where rule.MustNotContainAllOptions.All(option => !OptionList.Contains(option.OptionCode))
                              select rule.BillOfMaterial.BomNumber);
```

I can't seem to lock this down. If someone could explain what I am doing wrong that would be a great help.

Thank you

Comment: Could you perhaps make a more condensed/concise example?

Comment: Yes give me a few minutes I will try and condense it some more @OptimisticPeach

Comment: What seems to be going wrong with your code? What does "base" mean? You don't seem to be querying "a rule" but a database of rules?

Comment: @NetMage my mistake on the base, I condensed the code and forgot to remove that bit. And yes, I am querying a database of rules. I want to know if any of the rules satisfy the condition, if it does return that rules Bill Of Material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If OptionList is a list of Options, contains will not work on the optioncode.
You could do this if theyre the same reference or properly implemented valuetypes:

```
!OptionList.Contains(option)
```

or this if not:

```
!OptionList.Any(opt => opt.OptionCode == option.OptionCode)
```

your first query is wrong, you could change it to this...

```
where !rule.MustNotContainAllOptions.Any(option => OptionList
```

or use your 2nd query, which is correct

Comment: When I try your third example, I get an error that says "Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context"

Comment: It's incomplete, i was just saying if you wanted to use "Any" then you must make the query use "!" and the inner Contains check for true, rather than false.

I suggest sticking with your "All" query, as it's already correct

Comment: Ah I see, that was my mistake. Thank you for the answer. I will mark it as correct. It is hard for me to determine exactly how the any and all extension methods work.

Comment: @Selthien Think of `Any` as `Or` - e.g. a OR b OR c and `All` as `And`.